# Create file from string and download it

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I am having some issues with trying to create a file from a string and download it in ASP.NET Core.

What I am trying to do is that when a user presses a button I fetch some data as a string and create a file from it. In addition I would like to download this file to the pc. 
I have not been able to figure out a solution that works and so far this is the closest I have gotten:

```
    public async Task<FileStreamResult> DownloadFile()
    {
        string s = "Some string with data";

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms);

        await tw.WriteAsync(s);

        tw.Flush();

        return File(ms, "application/force-download", "readme.txt");
    }
```

The problem is that this does not work for some reason, the MemoryStream does not seem to stream the bytes of data to the file.

Comment: What do you mean by `does not work`? Are you getting any error? File doesn't download? File download as empty file? File has corrupted content?

Comment: If you create the string, why would you need to download it. You already have it.

Comment: You may need to rewind the MemoryStream (i.e. set `ms.Position = 0`) before calling the File method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert memory stream to `byte[]`:

```
public async Task<FileStreamResult> DownloadFile()
{
    string s = "Some string with data";

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms);

    await tw.WriteAsync(s);

    tw.Flush();

    byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
    ms.Close();

    return File(bytes, "application/force-download", "readme.txt");
}
```